# SQL SUM only returns first record

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT playerID, nameLast, SUM(IP), SUM(WAR)
FROM `mlb_pitchers`
WHERE (year >= '1903' and year <= '1906')
ORDER BY WAR
```

The above only returns the SUM of the first pitcher in the database. How do I get it to collect summations for all pitchers?

```
SELECT playerID, nameLast, SUM(IP), SUM(WAR)
FROM `mlb_pitchers`
WHERE playerID = 'mathech01' and (year >= '1903' and year <= '1906')
```

If I'm specific with the playerID, I do get a summation values for years 1903-1906.

Comment: Help us help you - please share the tables' structure, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get for it.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: It depends with your Database too, How many such entries are there? Maybe there is only one such entry. You can use SELECT ALL and hopefully you have more than one entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` like:

```
SELECT playerID, nameLast, SUM(IP), SUM(WAR)
FROM mlb_pitchers
where year >= '1903' and year <= '1906'
GROUP BY playerID, nameLast
ORDER BY SUM(WAR) desc
```

Comment: @user2140857 please check the answer and let me know your feedback.

Comment: This is the right kind of answer.  Using an aggregate function (like `SUM()`) without `GROUP BY` ensures your result set can have at most one row.

Comment: I'm trying to paste some sample table data but I don't remember how to do it.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'year' in 'having clause'

Comment: @user2140857 put sample data with column name

Comment: @user2140857 Remove having clause and use your year filter in where clause

Comment: @user2140857 just write the data in notepad like row column sets and paste it here

Comment: I'm too stupid to figure out how to paste the notepad data without it wrapping. Do I add a prefix and suffix to keep it from wrapping? Sorry, it's been awhile since I had to do this and I don't understand the help.

Comment: you can send any way so that I can understand like a para

Comment: year         playerID         nameLast IP WAR
1903 ablesha01 Ables  200 5.6
1903 mathech01 Mathewson 300 10.9
1904 ablesha01 Ables  100 3.3
1904 mathech01 Mathewson 290 9.8
1905 ablesha01 Ables  150 5
1905 mathech01 Mathewson 250 7.7
1906 ablesha01 Ables  175 7
1906 mathech01 Mathewson 350 14.6

Comment: SELECT playerID, nameLast, SUM(IP), SUM(WAR) FROM `mlb_pitchers` GROUP BY playerID, nameLast WHERE (year >= '1903' and year <= '1906')

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (year >= '1903' and year <= '1906') LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4

Comment: @user2140857 use the below query: 
`SELECT playerID, nameLast, SUM(IP), SUM(WAR)
FROM mlb_pitchers
where year >= '1903' and year <= '1906'
GROUP BY playerID, nameLast`

Comment: @user2140857 I am updating my answer as well

Comment: SELECT playerID, nameLast, SUM(IP), SUM(WAR) FROM mlb_pitchers where year >= '1903' and year <= '1906' GROUP BY playerID, nameLast - worked

Comment: @user2140857 please see the solution as an example (here) [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3fe15/9]

Comment: @user2140857 Thanks. please accept the answer and vote up

Comment: I will. Can I ask a follow up or do I have to open another question? I'd like the output to be sorted by the highest WAR sum value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161404/discussion-between-ali-azam-and-user2140857).